# Why does estimated odds ratio obtained in fisher.test() function different from calculated odds ratio?

Tags: r

Here is my contingency table:

```
X
#      Yes   No
# Pre    5  685
# Post  17 1351
```

Fisher Test

```
fisher.test(X)

#        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

# data:  X
# p-value = 0.3662
# alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
# 95 percent confidence interval:
# 0.1666371 1.6474344
# sample estimates:
# odds ratio 
# 0.5802157
```

Calculated Odds Ratio

```
P1<-5/(5+685)
P2<-17/(17+1351)
(P1/(1-P1))/(P2/(1-P2))
# [1] 0.5800773
```

Why are the values different? How does fisher test function in R calculate the estimated odds ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code underlying `fisher.test`, I see

```
ESTIMATE <- c(`odds ratio` = mle(x))
```

Immediately above this is

```
mle <- function(x) {
            if (x == lo) 
                return(0)
            if (x == hi) 
                return(Inf)
            mu <- mnhyper(1)
            if (mu > x) 
                uniroot(function(t) mnhyper(t) - x, c(0, 1))$root
            else if (mu < x) 
                1/uniroot(function(t) mnhyper(1/t) - x, c(.Machine$double.eps, 
                  1))$root
            else 1
        }
```

Without exploring all the details of the code above the `mle` definition, it looks like `fisher.test` is solving an equation for the odds based on theoretical assumptions defined in `mnhyper` (another function defined in `fisher.test`[1]) and not calculating it directly from the data. I suspect if I wanted to get a full answer, I would need to read the references in `?fisher.test`

[1] There are several functions in `fisher.test` such as `dnhyper`, `mnhyper`, and `pnhyper` which appear to be distribution functions for a non-central hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: In your opinion, which value of odds ratio should I report in my analysis?

Comment: Personally, I would round the odds ratio to the hundredth. I doubt you are likely to come across a scenario where the discrepancy even reaches the thousandth.